# How to implement a preference activity for download location in android

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager, preferenceactivity

I have developed an app which downloads some files from server. I'm using android download manager to download files to mobile device. I want to build a settings screen asking default location to store files using preference activity. How can i implement it.

I want to show all the storage options available in mobile in preference activity. Currently i'm using below line to store the files using download manage.

Here is the code:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + DownloadEntries.getFile_dest_path(), filepaths.get(i));
```

Please help. I'm new to android.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something called PreferenceFragment

Preference fragment is just an easy way of creating a settings screen in Android.

You can refer [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Settings-with-PreferenceFragment) for the Preference Fragments.

Since Preference Fragments doesn't support file pickers by default, you can use this library [here](https://github.com/Angads25/android-filepicker) for the file picker.

So you can tell the user to pick a folder and you can create your file in there.